# How to upgrade App\Exceptions from laravel 7 to laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

How to upgrade App\Exceptions; from laravel 7 to laravel 8

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
            if (Auth::user() instanceof Admin) {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: from the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` like follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```